# How to implement ++ in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Hi I'm new in Haskell programming. I'm trying to implement operator "++" by myself. Here's a small program I wrote but it won't work:

```
append (es:e) xs = 
    if (null es)
    then e:xs
    else append es (e:xs)
```

I received lots of type error with [a],[[a]] and [[[a]]]. Still confusing about the list type in Haskell. Can someone help me with that? Thank you. :)

Comment: @Bergi already explained how to rewrite this, but from reading your code I am getting the impression you were trying to pattern match on the *last* element of the list.  If that were possible, your code would have been much closer to working. (You would still have been missing the empty list case.) However, Haskell lists are linked lists starting at the front and you can *only* pattern match elements from the front end.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
append (es:e) xs =
        ^^^^
```

Typically, you would write `(e:es)`, which could be spoken "one e before a list of es". You actually have used this meaning below, but have told the compiler that `es` is an element and `e` is a list - which produces the type errors you received.

```
    if (null es)
```

That's not how you should test for an emtpy list. In fact, if you'd call `append [] …` you'd get a "non-exhaustive pattern" error, because `(e:es)` is always a list of at least one element. So try two patterns:

```
append []     xs = xs
append (e:es) xs = append es (e:xs)
```

However, this still doesn't work expected - the first list is actually reversed by this snippet. Instead, the first element (`e`) needs to go before the whole rest of the list (`es` and `xs`):

```
append (e:es) xs = e : (append es xs)
```

(and that's indeed [how `++` is implemented](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#%2B%2B))

Comment: To be pedantic, there's a rewrite rule which replaces this definition of `++` with `xs ++ ys = augment (\c n -> foldr c n xs) ys` in actual optimised GHC Haskell.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Ah, I see. I already wondered what that `RULE` thing meant :-)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Care to explain how that is an optimization?  It appears to be something to do with list fusion, I just haven't encountered it before so I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Comment: @bheklilr `augment` gives optimization when it's combined with the fusion rule `"foldr/augment" forall k z xs (g::forall b. (a->b->b) -> b -> b) . foldr k z (augment g xs) = g k (foldr k z xs)`, which ideally optimizes away most of the list allocation. `augment` differs from the similar `build` in that it's used to prepend stuff to a list rather than building the whole list. See [GHC.Base](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/src/GHC-Base.html#%2B%2B).